LiveChart WPF is not updating
Im making a LiveChart in WPF out of data that i get from VK API. I want the "period_from" and "period_to" values to change, when the user changes the month and the chart to update accordingly. I have made a function that converts DateTime to TimeStamp. Those variables work correctly, everything works. But the chart itself doesnt want to update.
This is my xaml:
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <lvc:CartesianChart Name="ViewsChart" Grid.Row="1" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Dates" Labels="{Binding BarLabels}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Views" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>


    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Май" Foreground="#C73F69" 
                    Name="MonthBlock"
                    FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0 15 50 20"/>

            <TextBlock Text="2024" 
Name="YearBlock"
FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0 15 0 20"/>


        </StackPanel>
      
        <Image Source="Icons/img_back.png"
    MouseDown="BackMonth_MouseDown"
Stretch="None"
Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Image Source="Icons/img_fd.png"
   Grid.Column="2"
   MouseDown="ForwardMonth_MouseDown"
Stretch="None"
Margin="0,0,0,0"/>


    </Grid>
</Grid> 

And this is the code behind it:
public partial class Window1 : Window
 {


    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] BarLabels { get; set; }//X - dates
    public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; } //Y - views


    public int current_year { get; set; } = 2024;
    public int current_month { get; set; } = 5;


    public string accessToken = //bla bla bla
    public string groupId = // bla bla bla
    public string apiVersion = "5.86";
    public long timestamp_from { get; set; }
    public long timestamp_to { get; set; }
    public string url;



    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        DataContext = this;
        set_list();
    }

    List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>();
    List<int> visitors = new List<int>();
    private void GetNewSubscribersStatistics()
    {
        url = $"https://api.vk.com/method/stats.get?group_id={groupId}&access_token={accessToken}&timestamp_from={timestamp_from}&timestamp_to={timestamp_to}&v={apiVersion}";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string response;

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }


        Stat stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stat>(response);

        times.Clear();
        visitors.Clear();
         
         
        foreach (var s in stats.response)
        {
            DateTime dat_Time = new DateTime(1965, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            dat_Time = dat_Time.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(s.period_from));
            times.Add(dat_Time);
            visitors.Add(s.visitors.views);
        }
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<int>(visitors)
            }
        };
        BarLabels = times.ToArray();
        Formatter = value => value.ToString("N");

        DataContext = this;

        ViewsChart.Update();
    }


private void BackMonth_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (current_month == 1)
        {
            current_month = 12;
            current_year -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            current_month -= 1;
        }
        set_list();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Передвигаем месяц на один вперед
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ForwardMonth_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (current_month == 12)
        {
            current_month = 1;
            current_year += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            current_month += 1;
        }
        set_list();
    }

    private void set_list()
    {
        MonthBlock.Text = Month_Translate_ToRus(current_month);
        DateTime dt_from = new DateTime(current_year, current_month, 1);
        DateTime dt_to = new DateTime(current_year, current_month, set_day(current_month));

        timestamp_from = ConvertToTimestamp(dt_from);
        timestamp_to = ConvertToTimestamp(dt_to);

        
        GetNewSubscribersStatistics();
         
    }

    
/// <summary>
    /// How many days does a month have
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int set_day(int m)
    {
        int month =     m == 1 ? 31 :       current_year % 4 == 0 && m == 2 ? 29 : current_year % 4 != 0 && m == 2 ? 28    : m == 3 ? 31 : m == 4 ? 30 : m == 5 ? 31 : m == 6 ? 30 : m == 7 ? 31 : m == 8 ? 31 : m == 9 ? 30 : m == 10 ? 31 : m == 11 ? 30 : 31;
        return month;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Переводит название месяца с числа на русский язык
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string Month_Translate_ToRus(int m)
    { 
        var month = m == 1 ? "Январь" : m == 2 ? "Февраль" : m == 3 ? "Март" : m == 4 ? "Апрель" : m == 5 ? "Май" : m == 6 ? "Июнь" : m == 7 ? "Июль" : m == 8 ? "Август" : m == 9 ? "Сентябрь" : m == 10 ? "Октябрь" : m == 11 ? "Ноябрь" : "Декабрь";
        return month;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Переводит DateTime в Timestamp
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
    {
        long epoch = (value.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
        return epoch;
    }
}

And theres also a class to get the Statistics
public class StatResponse
{

    public string period_from;
    public string period_to;
    public Visitors visitors;
}
public class Visitors
{
    public int views;
}

public class Stat
{
    public List<StatResponse> response { get; set; }
}

Ive tried debugging the code, all the variables update well, but the chart doesnt(

I can't see any INotifyPropertyChanged, try to change List<DateTime> to ObservableCollection<DateTime> and List<int> to ObservableCollection<int>

Also, please don't use obsolete HttpWebRequest. There is HttpClient for any HTTP requests.
